# What to do when the residuals of a general LMM are non normal and a generlized LMM will not build, when is it just too non-normal?

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, glmm

I've been having no luck building a general LMM. The residuals are not normally distributed, they follow somewhat of a leptokurtic distribution and homoskedacity is also present. Using log transformation of the dependant variable fixes the homoskedacity but the long tails on the QQ plot are still present:

[image]

The obvious solution, fitting a generalized LMM with a gamma distribution to the same data results in a failure to converge. Reducing the complexity of the model to only 2 fixed effects and one random effects doesn't solve the convergence problems. I've tried using different optimizers, using starting parameters from the general LLM and increasing the number of iterations to 10000, but without success.

```
start_values <- getME(model1, "theta")
control_params <- glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", tol = 1e-5, optCtrl = list(maxfun = 10000))

gmodel1 <- glmer(value ~ treatment + phase + (treatment|person),
                data = Data_all,
                family = Gamma(link = "log"),
                start = start_values,
                control = control_params)
```

I also tried using the heavyLme function from the heavy package. It works, but I'm not really sure if I should use it, since it doesn't seem to be all that popular, the package has been removed from the CRAN repo. But at least the QQ plots looks neat.

[image]

My question is, when are the residuals too non-normally distributed for the model to be valid. Also in general if you have any tips on what to do. Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Two possibilities would be to use robust estimation (`rlmer` from the `robustlmm` package) or t-distributed residuals (with the `glmmTMB` package, using `family = t_family`). The `mgcv` package has `family = scat`, but I don't think `mgcv` will handle this particular flavour of mixed model (i.e., it can easily handle `(1|f)` effects via `s(..., bs = "re")`, but I don't think it can do RE of the form `(x|f)`).